# Can i use divide in loop for PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop

Can i use divide in loop for PHP ?

I write code like that but not work.

```
<?PHP
    for ($k=100;$k>2;$k/2)
        {echo $k;}
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should be `$k = $k / 2`, or `$k /= 2`.

As pointed out in the comments, you could also use a bit shift operation `$k >>= 1`.

Comment: or you could go leet with `$k<<=1`

Comment: @krowe You could go even more leet by doing the bit shift in the right direction ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
for ($k=100;$k>2;$k = $k/2) {
    echo $k;
}
```